# How show success message in Ajax call success function in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to show case the success message, if I get the ajax call response status 200 but I am not able to get the alert even when I get the status code 200 . where I am doing wrong here. any please help me on it. and if possible please show me the answer in js fiddle .

```js
$("#check").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1',
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
      // alert('getting into success');
      console.log(response);
      if (response.status == 200) {

        alert('getting into success');
      }
    },
    error: function(err) {
      alert(err);
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.js" integrity="sha256-a9jBBRygX1Bh5lt8GZjXDzyOB+bWve9EiO7tROUtj/E=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <button id="check" value="check">Check</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: does your `console.log(response);` returns an object with the property `status` on it?

Comment: Yes I'm getting api response status code 200 but in success function success message not getting

Comment: `response.status` is not the HTTP status code, it comes from your JSON.

Comment: Yes correct. but how to do in jQuery ajax call

Comment: The `success:` function will only be executed when there's a 200 status, you don't need to check that in your function.